# Accessing Variables in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, actionlistener

If I have the following Java code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
class GuessMyNumber extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InputBox box = new InputBox("Guess a number between 1 and 100:");
        box.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        box.setSize(360, 360);
        box.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

InputBox class:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
public class InputBox extends JFrame {
    private JLabel text1;
    private JTextField textField1;
    public InputBox(String prompt) {
        super("Guess My Number");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        text1 = new JLabel(prompt);
        add(text1);
        textField1 = new JTextField(20);
        add(textField1);
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        textField1.addActionListener(handler);
    }
    private class Handler implements ActionListener {
        String in = "";
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            if (event.getSource() == textField1) {
                in = event.getActionCommand();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I access `in` from the main class? I'm an absolute beginner with GUI's in Java, so please don't be too harsh!

Thanks

Comment: I don't know what you want to do with the `String`, but why not do it in the `actionPerformed` method?

Answer (score 1):

Move declaration of `in` to `InputBox` class. You can set frame type to modal (`setModal(true)`), and call `dispose()` method from `ActionListener`, then your main thread will block until user enter some number.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact you could have much easier code than u currently have, here is a solution:

move the Handler out of InputBox or make it non private, and then provide a getter in Handler class.

1)

```
private class Handler implements ActionListener {
        String in = "";
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            if (event.getSource() == textField1) {
                in = event.getActionCommand();
            }
        }
        public String getValue(){
        return in;
        }
    }
```

then you can access it through Handler Object.

2) or more easy way would be, Move your `in` variable declaration in `InputBox` and provide a getter there.

Comment: The `Handler` class is private.